# Java Events - Generating Mouse Events

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, mouselistener

Does anyone see whats wrong? Why the actionListener is not picking up on the event?

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main extends JFrame {

        JButton button = new JButton("MouseEventTest");

        public Main() {
                super("MouseEventTest");
                setSize(400, 200);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
                setResizable(false);
                setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                setVisible(true);
                add(button);
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                System.out.println("ID: " + e.getID());
                        }      
                });

                clickMouse(button, 50, 50);
        }

        private void clickMouse(Component c, int x, int y) {
                button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(c, MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, x, y, 1, false));
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
                new Main();
        }

}
```

Comment: Please do not use pastebin for code samples.

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot so far? Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: It ssems to work correctly on my side. Please check once again.

Comment: Works fine for me. Windows XP - java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Fails to work on Java 7, Windows 7 unless then event includes a `MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK` modifier

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong with the posted code:

1. A GUI should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Read the Swing tutorial and read some of the examples to see the proper way to create the GUI.
2. Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.

But the main reason your clickButton(...) method doesn't work is because an ActionEvent is generated when a mousePressed and a mouseReleased is generated by the user on the button. This is different that a mouseClicked event.

If all you want to do is click a button in your program then just invoke:

```
button.doClick();
```

Comment: Im aware that I should use the EDT, and that components should be added to the frame before it is set visible, however this was just quick work to test wether or not this would work, and also this was a test for other components. I want to send mouseEvents to an applet.

Comment: @ChrisGray `however this was just quick work to test wether or not this would work` - When you have a problem you don't know if the problem exists because you are taking shortcuts or not, so post proper code if you want us to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but after having dug around the source code a little bit, the `BasicButtonUI` is expecting a left mouse click.

The mouse button is determined by event modifiers, which you've set to `0`.  Also, the action event is only trigged on the mouse released event, not clicked.

So you would need to create you event more like...

```
button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(c, MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(), MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK, x, y, 1, false));
```

Now, having said that, as camickr has pointed out, it's possible that the button hasn't being realised on screen before your `clickMouse` method is executed, meaning that it may ignore the event.

You should also be careful, executing an event out of sequence or not fulfilling the remaining event expectations in this manner may place your UI into an invalid state.  For example, on press, there is an expectation of a release and possibly a clicked mouse event...

So, to be quite frank.. `JButton#doClick` would be a more suitable solution...IMHO

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MouseButton extends JFrame {

    JButton button = new JButton("MouseEventTest");

    public MouseButton() {
        super("MouseEventTest");
        setSize(400, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("ID: " + e.getID());
            }
        });


        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                clickMouse(button, 50, 50);
            }

        });

    }

    private void clickMouse(Component c, int x, int y) {
        button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(c, MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(), MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK, x, y, 1, false));
        button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(c, MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, System.currentTimeMillis(), MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK, x, y, 1, false));
        button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(c, MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, System.currentTimeMillis(), MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK, x, y, 1, false));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MouseButton();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: `the action event is only trigged on the mouse pressed event, not clicked.` - No, as I stated you need both pressed and released events. This is easy to test. Just press the mouse and move it around before you release it. The event is only fired on the release. Or press it down and then move the mouse off of the component and no event is generated.

Comment: @camickrThe `actionEvent` must be triggered BEFORE (my) `mouseReleased` event as my output occurs between pressed and released - I don't doubt your comment as I know it's true as soon as I read it, getting confused by my output...

Comment: +1, for specifying the left mouse button in the event (I didn't even look that since I new two events needed to be dispatched). Also note that you don't need to dispatch the mouseClicked() event. This is not a requirement for the ActionEvent to be generated.

Comment: @camickr Agreed, once release is called, clicked becomes irrelevant, just trying to keep expectations in line in case something else is listening ;)